# Orderer bootstrap failed: CA Certificate did not have the CA attribute

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I followed this tutorial [Fabric CA Operations Guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/orderer_deploy.html) and made a small change that I had deleted the org2. When I tried to bootstrap orderer (startOrder()) I got this problem:

```
orderer1-org0    |  Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
orderer1-org0    |  Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
orderer1-org0    |  Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
orderer1-org0    | 2020-01-17 08:38:42.755 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> PANI 003 Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: CA Certificate did not have the CA attribute, (SN: 333bd2e7c3a72c1cde58a74d599487437e053834)
orderer1-org0    | panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: CA Certificate did not have the CA attribute, (SN: 333bd2e7c3a72c1cde58a74d599487437e053834)
orderer1-org0    | 
orderer1-org0    | goroutine 1 [running]:
orderer1-org0    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc000189970, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
orderer1-org0    |  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x546
orderer1-org0    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc000010188, 0x16ab104, 0x1552904, 0x25, 0xc000173cd0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
orderer1-org0    |  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x101
orderer1-org0    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)
orderer1-org0    |  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159
orderer1-org0    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(...)
orderer1-org0    |  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74
orderer1-org0    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0x15309fe, 0x5, 0xc00069c900)
orderer1-org0    |  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:98 +0xe5
orderer1-org0    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
orderer1-org0    |  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:91 +0x208
orderer1-org0    | main.main()
orderer1-org0    |  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
orderer1-org0 exited with code 2
```

I have retried servial times but got the same problems. I wonder what and where the CA attribute should be provided?

bash shell:

```
function rootca() {
    docker-compose -f dp-scecochain-ca.yaml up -d ca-tls
    echo "wait for 10s to start ca-tls"
    sleep 5
    mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/tls-ca/crypto/"
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/tls-ca/crypto/tls-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/tls-ca/crypto/tls-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/tls-ca/admin
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://tls-ca-admin:tls-ca-adminpw@0.0.0.0:7052
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name peer1-org1 --id.secret peer1PW --id.type peer -u https://0.0.0.0:7052
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name peer2-org1 --id.secret peer2PW --id.type peer -u https://0.0.0.0:7052
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name peer1-org2 --id.secret peer1PW --id.type peer -u https://0.0.0.0:7052
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name peer2-org2 --id.secret peer2PW --id.type peer -u https://0.0.0.0:7052
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name orderer1-org0 --id.secret ordererPW --id.type orderer -u https://0.0.0.0:7052
}

function org0ca {
    docker-compose -f dp-scecochain-ca.yaml up -d rca-org0
    sleep 5
    #mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org0/ca/crypto/"
    #cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org0/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org0/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org0/ca/admin
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://rca-org0-admin:rca-org0-adminpw@0.0.0.0:7053
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name orderer1-org0 --id.secret ordererpw --id.type orderer -u https://0.0.0.0:7053
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name admin-org0 --id.secret org0adminpw --id.type admin --id.attrs "hf.Registrar.Roles=client,hf.Registrar.Attributes=*,hf.Revoker=true,hf.GenCRL=true,admin=true:ecert,abac.init=true:ecert" -u https://0.0.0.0:7053
}

function org1ca() {
    docker-compose -f dp-scecochain-ca.yaml up -d rca-org1
    sleep 5
    #mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org1/ca/crypto/"
    #cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/ca/admin
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://rca-org1-admin:rca-org1-adminpw@0.0.0.0:7054
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name peer1-org1 --id.secret peer1PW --id.type peer -u https://0.0.0.0:7054
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name peer2-org1 --id.secret peer2PW --id.type peer -u https://0.0.0.0:7054
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name admin-org1 --id.secret org1AdminPW --id.type user -u https://0.0.0.0:7054
    fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name user-org1 --id.secret org1UserPW --id.type user -u https://0.0.0.0:7054
}




function startPeer() {
    mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/ca/"
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org1/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/ca/org1-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/ca/org1-ca-cert.pem
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://peer1-org1:peer1PW@0.0.0.0:7054

    mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/tls-ca/"
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls/ca/crypto/tls-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=tls-msp
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://peer1-org1:peer1PW@0.0.0.0:7052 --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts peer1-org1


    mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/assets/ca/"
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org1/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/assets/ca/org1-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/assets/ca/org1-ca-cert.pem
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://peer2-org1:peer2PW@0.0.0.0:7054

    mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/assets/tls-ca/"
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls/ca/crypto/tls-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/assets/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=tls-msp
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/assets/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://peer2-org1:peer2PW@0.0.0.0:7052 --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts peer2-org1


    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/admin
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/ca/org1-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://admin-org1:org1AdminPW@0.0.0.0:7054

    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org2/admin
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/assets/ca/org1-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://admin-org1:org1AdminPW@0.0.0.0:7054


    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/msp/admincerts
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/msp/admincerts
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org1/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/msp/admincerts/org1-admin-cert.pem
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org1/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/msp/admincerts/org1-admin-cert.pem


    #rename to /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/tls-msp/keystore  key.pem
    mv /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/tls-msp/keystore/*_sk /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem
    mv /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/tls-msp/keystore/*_sk /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer2/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem
    docker-compose -f dp-scecochain-ca.yaml up -d peer1-org1
    docker-compose -f dp-scecochain-ca.yaml up -d peer2-org1
}


function genesis() {

    mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/ca"
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org0/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/ca/org0-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/ca/org0-ca-cert.pem
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://orderer1-org0:ordererpw@0.0.0.0:7053

    mkdir -p "/tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/tls-ca/"
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls/ca/crypto/tls-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=tls-msp
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/tls-ca/tls-ca-cert.pem
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://orderer1-org0:ordererPW@0.0.0.0:7052 --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts orderer1-org0
    mv /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/tls-msp/keystore/*_sk /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem


    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/org0/admin
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/ca/org0-ca-cert.pem
    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://admin-org0:org0adminpw@0.0.0.0:7053
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/msp/admincerts
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org0/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/msp/admincerts/orderer-admin-cert.pem


    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp/admincerts
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp/cacerts
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp/tlscacerts
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org0/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp/admincerts/orderer-admin-cert.pem
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/assets/ca/org0-ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp/cacerts/org0-ca-cert.pem
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls-ca/crypto/tls-ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp/admincerts
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp/cacerts
    mkdir /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp/tlscacerts
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org1/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp/admincerts/admin-org1-cert.pem
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/org1/ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp/cacerts/org1-ca-cert.pem
    cp /tmp/hyperledger/tls-ca/crypto/tls-ca-cert.pem /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem

    configtxgen -profile OrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/genesis.block
    configtxgen -profile OrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx /tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/channel.tx -channelID mychannel
}

function startOrder(){
    docker-compose -f dp-scecochain-ca.yaml up orderer1-org0
}



function networkDown() {
    docker-compose -f dp-scecochain-ca.yaml down
    sleep 10
    docker volume prune -f
    rm -rf /tmp/hyperledger/*
}
```

And the configtx.yaml

```
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    - &org0

        Name: org0

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: org0MSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: /tmp/hyperledger/org0/msp

    - &org1

        Name: org1

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: org1MSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer1-org1
              Port: 7051


################################################################################
#
#   CAPABILITIES
#
#   This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    # Note that setting a later Channel version capability to true will also
    # implicitly set prior Channel version capabilities to true. There is no need
    # to set each version capability to true (prior version capabilities remain
    # in this sample only to provide the list of valid values).
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.4.3 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.4.3
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.4.3 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.4.3 or later.
        V1_4_3: true
        # V1.3 for Channel enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3
        V1_3: false
        # V1.1 for Channel enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1
        V1_1: false

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    # Note that setting a later Orderer version capability to true will also
    # implicitly set prior Orderer version capabilities to true. There is no need
    # to set each version capability to true (prior version capabilities remain
    # in this sample only to provide the list of valid values).
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.4.2 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.4.2
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.4.2 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.4.2 or later.
        V1_4_2: true
        # V1.1 for Orderer enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1
        V1_1: false

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    # Note that setting a later Application version capability to true will also
    # implicitly set prior Application version capabilities to true. There is no need
    # to set each version capability to true (prior version capabilities remain
    # in this sample only to provide the list of valid values).
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.4.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.4.2
        V1_4_2: true
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: false
        # V1.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.2 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set)
        V1_2: false
        # V1.1 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set).
        V1_1: false


################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:


################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    OrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
            # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
            OrdererType: solo
            Addresses:
            - orderer1-org0:7050

            # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
            BatchTimeout: 2s

            # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
            BatchSize:

                # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
                MaxMessageCount: 10

                # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
                # the serialized messages in a batch.
                AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

                # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
                # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
                # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
                PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

            # Kafka:
            #   # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
            #   # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
            #   Brokers:
            #     - 127.0.0.1:9092

            # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
            # the orderer side of the network
            Organizations:
            - *org0

        Consortiums:

            SampleConsortium:

                Organizations:
                    - *org1

    OrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
           <<: *ApplicationDefaults
           Organizations:
           - *org1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CA root (or intermediate) certificate must include:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
```

If you check your `org1-ca-cert.pem`...

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in org1-ca-cert.pem
```

...I bet you'll see it does not include that attribute.

I don't know how you created your CA's certificates, but Fabric-CA automatically creates its suitable root certificates when being created if you configure non-existing file names. If, for any reason, you want to create it manually, you can create a configuration file similar to...

```
[req]
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn
x509_extensions = x509_ext

[dn]
CN = mydomain.com
C = US
ST = New York
L = New York
O = MyOrg
OU = MyDepartment

[x509_ext]
basicConstraints=critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:2
keyUsage=critical, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = mydomain.com
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

...and run...

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -days 7300 -config csr.cnf
```

Comment: Then, you must be including any other certificate in the `cacerts` folder of any MSP that does not include the `CA:TRUE`. Look at the orderer's configured MSP folder and the `MSPDir`s of your `configtx.yaml` when generating the ordering service genesis block.

Comment: thank you @kekomal. I have checked the org0-ca-cert.pem  and org1-ca-cert.pem and found something like this:
```
X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:1
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                A5:07:7A:FD:2C:78:86:ED:DC:0D:64:03:85:C7:91:AF:FC:2B:4B:AE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                IP Address:0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Yes, it's about CAs. There was a bug in my shell and I've fixed it. Everything goes well when CAs are in the right places. Thank you @kekomal